# FlatList not updated if data updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a FlatList with data fetched from an API. There's a button on the screen that fetches data which is changed and sets the state, but the flat list doesn't refresh. I tried setting the extraData as per docs, but it didn't help. Here are the full code and snack.

If you click the Toggle List button, the alert correctly shows the new data, but the list isn't updated.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const DATA2 = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'D2-0'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'D2-1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'D2-2'
  },
];

const DATA1 = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'D1-0'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'D1-1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'D1-2'
  },
];

export default function App(props) {
  const [data, setData]=useState(DATA1);
  const [dataUsed, setDataUsed]=useState(1);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <MyComponent data={item} /> }
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        extraData={data}
      />
      <Button title="Toggle Data" onPress={() => {
        let newData = dataUsed === 1 ? DATA2 : DATA1;
        setDataUsed(dataUsed === 1 ? 2: 1);
        alert(JSON.stringify(newData));
        setData(newData);
      }} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: props.data};
  }
  render() {
    return <Text>{this.state.data.title}</Text>;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    padding: 50
  }
});
```

```html
<div data-snack-id="SkDYPf4wH" data-snack-platform="web" data-snack-preview="true" data-snack-theme="light" style="overflow:hidden;background:#fafafa;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%"></div>
<script async src="https://snack.expo.io/embed.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missed the reflection of the state.
Once you set the state, it could be reflected next time.
Do I think you need to use the Hook.
Please try to use it.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
... ... ...
export default function App(props) {
  const [data, setData]=useState(DATA1);
  const [dataUsed, setDataUsed]=useState(1);

useEffect(()=>{
 let newData = dataUsed === 1 ? DATA2 : DATA1;
 setData(newData);
},[setData, dataUsed]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <MyComponent data={item} /> }
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        extraData={data}
      />
      <Button title="Toggle Data" onPress={() => {
        setDataUsed(dataUsed === 1 ? 2: 1);
        alert(JSON.stringify(newData));
      }} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

And for the component.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: props.data};
  }
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if( prevProps.data !== this.props.data ){
    this.setData();
  }
}
setData = ()=>{
  this.setState({
   data: this.props.data,   
  });
}
  Render () {
    return <Text>{this.state.data.title}</Text>;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `MyComponent` code like this

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Text>{this.props.data.title}</Text>;
  }
}
```

Your `constructor` code is actually useless.